# Dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I'm new here!

I'm also relatively new to Ubuntu in general. I've got a System76 machine (Sable Touch, 2014), and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

My university offers Windows 10 to all students for free, and I decided to take advantage of the offer and download the ISO. I've run Windows on here through a virtual machine, but I'd really like to dual boot for some gaming and more intense data analysis programs I need to use through Windows.

From what I've read, it's not wise or easy to install Windows now or dual boot with Ubuntu already installed, so I think what I need to do is start from scratch, right? That is, I need to install Windows on the computer fresh and then install Ubuntu so I can dual boot.

Can someone explain this process to me or point me to some resources? I'm not computer illiterate, but I'm far from a programmer. ;) Basically what I need to know is whether (and how!) I need to remove Ubuntu from my computer before I try to install Windows from my external hard drive.

Thanks for your help, and apologies for any ignorance on my part!

Mark

Comment: You don't need to remove Ubuntu, just shrink some partition to make room for Windows. That's not the problem. The problem is you won't have drivers. System76 machines are provided with Ubuntu and this OS is the only one supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for your help!

Just found this on drivers as well... http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/system76/laptops-desktops/sable-touch/245036

Comment: You're welcome, and regarding drivers you're on your own. Installing Windows and Windows drivers is not supported by the manufacturer and, obviously, off-topic here.

Comment: System76 has [a short article on locating Windows drivers for its systems](http://support.system76.com/articles/windows-drivers/).

Comment: Try this [guide](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2955460/operating-systems/dual-booting-linux-with-windows-what-you-need-to-know.html)  for such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

I googled your question and WebupD8 has [an article](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/make-bootable-windows-10-usb-install.html) about making Windows 10 bootable media for installing Windows. This should help to create the usb. For the dual boot you should try:

Make space about at least 50GB(since you were talking about games) space as "unallocated". You can use the program Gparted for it.

After you created your partition, start the computer from your USB drive that you made that to Windows usb and start to install Windows but when you come to the hard [disk part](http://www.howtogeek.com/197647/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-with-windows-7-or-8/) choose the Unallocated partition that you created and continue(if you have problem than you can format it from that part or using diskpart in the repair part). I didin't try it before so i don't know that Windows overrides Windows Boot Manager to GRUB, but dual boot should be done. Besides you wont touch other partitions so you won't break the ubuntu part.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP is trying to install Windows alongside Ubuntu, not the other way around.

Comment: @KazWolfe solution updated thanks for the warning.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've gone ahead and edited out the stricken part of the answer and reversed my downvote on your post. Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Yoy will just need to reinstall grub after installung windows 10.

Make an ntfs partition to install windows 10 to before you get started with the install so that there is a place to install windows to.

You should be able to either usr bootrepair or manually reinstall grub after installing windows 10.

These two mentioned solutions have been outlined in previous questions if you are not familiar with either one of these methods.